# Swift Today Extension preferredContentSize not resizing

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

so like the description says I am working on an iOS App and wanted to create a Today Extension Widget for it. My Problem is that I wanted to change the height to 200. After researching the only solution I found was to use the preferredContentSize atribute but this wasn't working for me.

I want to add a tableView to it and I wanted it to beshould be fully shown.
I added the viewDidLoad method so you can see where the table is created and added.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.iOSApp")!
    let eventData = myDefaults.object(forKey: "events")

    if eventData != nil {
        shownEvents = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: eventData as! Data) as! [Event]
    }

    eventTable = UITableView()
    eventTable.register(TodayViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    eventTable.separatorColor = UIColor.primary()
    view.addSubview(eventTable)
    eventTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var tempX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventTable, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    var tempY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventTable, attribute: .top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) 
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([tempX, tempY])

    tempX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventTable, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    tempY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: eventTable, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)   
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([tempX, tempY])


    eventTable.delegate = self
    eventTable.dataSource = self

    eventTable.reloadData()

    preferredContentSize.height = 200


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iOS 10 setting preferredContentSize.height directly not work

after iOS 10, there are two type to show today extension

case 1 Show More (expanded type, can set custom height)

case 2 Show Less (compact type, has default hegiht)

[image]

[What's new in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/whats-new/)

so you should provide height for iOS 10 earlier versions and for iOS 10

```
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
        //setup display mode (show more(.expended) or show less(.compact))
        extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        preferredContentSize.height = 200
    }
```

and shoulde implement for custom height

`func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {`

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    switch activeDisplayMode {
    case .expanded: preferredContentSize.height = 200
    case .compact: preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
}
```